# Enter with no input as a valid boolean

Tags: ruby

I'm writing some very simple code, asking for confirmation on a text input, and 
what I want to do is that if the users simply presses "Enter", make it count as a "yes". For example:

```
define method
        puts "enter some text"
        @text= gets.chomp
        puts "you entered '#{@text}', is it correct?"
        correct = gets.chomp    
             if correct == 'y' || ''
             other_method
             else
             method
        end
end
```

But when I run it on Ruby, I get the "Warning, literal string in condition", and whatever you enter, calls the "other_method". The solution I found is the following:

```
define method
        puts "enter some text"
        @text= gets.chomp
        puts "you entered '#{@text}', is it correct?"
        correct = gets.chomp    
             if correct == 'y'
             other_method
             elsif correct == ''
             other_method
             else
             method
        end
end
```

But it's pretty annoying, I'd rather understand why the first one doesn't work, and how can I make it work using the | |

Thank you!

Comment: In Ruby we prefer two-spaces for indentation:)

Comment: This isn't Ruby code as far as I can tell. It's `def method` but `method` is not a very good method name as there's already `Object#method` which you'd be breaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the error is saying is that you are supplying a string (literal) inside of a conditional statement by itself. When you do `if correct == "y" || ""` you're actually telling it `if correct == "y"` OR `""` and just supplying the string by itself is not a condition.

To fix this you'd simply supply the condition after the operator as well as before it. Ruby does not assume you want the same thing to happen after the `||`.

Like this:

```
define method
        puts "enter some text"
        @text= gets.chomp
        puts "you entered '#{@text}', is it correct?"
        correct = gets.chomp    
             if correct == 'y' || correct == ''
             other_method
             else
             method
        end
end
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding

Comment: Thanks! That helped!

Comment: Awesome. Again, happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

The solution here is to use Ruby's very versatile `case` statement to set up a number of "cases" you want to test:

```
puts "you entered '#{@text}', is it correct?"

case (gets.chomp)
when 'y', 'yes', ''
  method_a
else
  method_b
end
```

This can be extended to use regular expressions for even more versatility:

```
case (gets.chomp)
when /\A\s*y(?:es)?\s*\z/i
  method_a
else
  method_b
end
```

Where now anything like `"y"` or `"yes"` or `"Yes "` will work.

When you have bunch of `if` statements all testing the same variable, consider using a `case` statement to simplify your logic.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using **Regex** ([Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html)):

```
puts "enter some text"
@text= gets.chomp
puts "you entered '#{@text}', is it correct?"
correct = gets.chomp
if /^y?$/ =~ correct      # This will match 'y' and empty string both
  other_method
else
  method
end
```

Comment: I am quite a newby (some video tutorials constitute all my knowledge of programming), and your answer led me to regular expressions, which apparently are quite important, so I'm gonna do some reading on the subject to improve my coding. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good to hear. Go get'em. :)

Comment: In Ruby there's a big difference between `^` and `\A` as well as `$` and `\z`. `^` means *beginning of line* and `\A` means *beginning of string*. Same goes for the other two, relatively speaking.